# Cannot "Update Attributes" of more than 999 products

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, admin-panel

I've migrated to a new server, all magento files have remained the same. The only difference is that I am using CentOS 7 and MariaDB as apposed to CentOS 6.5 and MySQL.

When selecting "All" products (60k) --> Update Attributes when saving the message **Total of 999 record(s) were updated***

This is despite having selected "All" with the correct number of products selected.

EDIT: This is obviously not an isolated problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15497123/magento-why-cant-i-update-all-products-from-admin-grid

What steps can be taken to trouble shoot and resolve this issue?

Comment: when you select "All" products, does it say "999 product(s) selected" or "60123 product(s) selected" ?

Comment: Mmm weird. Is it always 999 products updated, or does it vary? How long does it take on average.

Comment: If no one answers in the next week, you might have stumbled apon a bug, which you should report [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking)

Comment: Please reopen. This problem is based on the introduction of `max_input_vars` which needs to be raised - a lot. http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-vars

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt thank you some people are way too quick on the closing trigger.

Comment: This has been a 'feature' of Magento for at least two years. I am not actually sure it is to do with the max_input_vars as I tried the same with collection objects even iterating them and hitting the 999 limit. This was on a project I no longer work on, however, it has been seen, again on a CentOS based build.

Comment: How about a vote to repoen @Woolfie so we can get a solution. Clearly I'm not the only one who has this issue.

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt should I delete the question and re-post? This is ridiculous.

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt is right, this is a issue with "max_input_vars"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP introduced in version 5.3.9 a new configuration variable called `max_input_vars` with default setting is 1000. So only the first 1000 variables are read from `POST` and `GET`.

PHP introduced this, because there is an attack vector, to be precious a Denial of Service vector to shut down PHP. This happens, because PHP calculates hashes to store "array" values in a hash map. If the hash already exists, it is recalculated. If this hash already exists, it is rerecalulcated and so on. Afaik this "bug" is not fixed, but limited to max_input_var. More on this on [security.stackexchange.com](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/54684/php-and-max-input-vars-configuration)

So to fix this problem, you can either change the `php.ini`, your `VHost configuration` or put the raised setting in `.htaccess`

Comment: Using: max_input_vars = 10000; did the trick.